# Oracle Database 11g on Mac OS with wine

Tags: database, oracle, macos, wine

I saw that Oracle Database 11 g is not available natively on Mac OS so is it possible to use it with wine? Does it work fine?

Comment: Oracle TechNet offers VMs for VirtualBox, which does run on MacOS. [Find them here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html). The current set has 12c but you may be able to find the older 11g images.

Comment: I knew there was this kind of solution, but I wanted to know if it is possible to run the windows exe through wine